# backbone.js view events don't get destroyed

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, click

I am trying to destroy a view/unbind all events when the view is not required any more. What I do is :

```
view.$el.removeData().unbind(); 
view.undelegateEvents();
view.remove();
```

The view gets destroyed, I can no longer see the associated element in the DOM, but events seem to persist. I am using Chrome developer tools and inspect memory usage and I see that every time I render the view and then destroy it the event listeners go up by one.

I tried to output the view events by doing:

```
this.$el.data("events");
```

but this gives me undefined.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Does you view contains children views? You should unbind/remove them too

Answer (score 2):

This excellent article describes how to prevent memory leaks in Backbone: http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/how-to-detect-backbone-memory-leaks/

His complete routine to destroy a view goes like this:

```
this.unbind(); // Unbind all local event bindings
this.model.unbind( 'change', this.render, this ); // Unbind reference to the model
this.options.parent.unbind( 'close:all', this.close, this ); // Unbind reference to the parent view

this.remove(); // Remove view from DOM

delete this.$el; // Delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
delete this.el; // Delete the variable reference to this node
```